# Why h2 doesn't see table that was just migrated?

Tags: java, spring-boot, h2, flyway

I have a Spring Boot web service backed by PostgreSQL 10. Since there were a few rounds of development Flyway is used to apply all necessary changes in DB.
Now I need to cover one of our modules with test and thus I need to mock PostgreSQL and I decided to use H2. The weird part is that when I run test I can see that I have no problems with DB migration, but when I try to use repository I get

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "MY_TABLE" not found; SQL statement:
```

I've tried to switch H2 to PostgreSQL mode with MODE=PostgreSQL and DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE in connection url, but it didn't help. Also I keep connection open with DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1. SQL queries in Flyway scripts seems fine, because on any attempt to modify them I can easily get syntax error.

Config properties

```
driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
url: jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_UPPER=FALSE;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
username: sa
password: sa
```

Test class

```java
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyConfig.class)
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class MailServiceTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyRepo repo;

    @Test
    public void x() throws Exception {
        repo.findAll(); // exception is thrown here
    }
}
```

Config class

```java
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class)
@PropertySource("classpath:custom-application.properties")
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.example.myproj"})
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.myproj", entityManagerFactoryRef = "customEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "customTransactionManager")
@EntityScan(basePackages = "com.example.myproj")
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableJpaAuditing(auditorAwareRef = "customAuditorAware")
@EnableScheduling
public class MyConfig {
...
}
```

Any clue how to fix this or at least where to look for solution? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just stuck on the same issue this morning.

Solution was in a configuration inherited from AbstractJdbcConfiguration to change quote handling:

```java
@Bean
@Override
public JdbcMappingContext jdbcMappingContext(Optional<NamingStrategy> namingStrategy, JdbcCustomConversions customConversions) {

    JdbcMappingContext mappingContext = super.jdbcMappingContext(namingStrategy, customConversions);
  mappingContext.setForceQuote(false);

    return mappingContext;
}
```

TL;DR

Using JdbcTemplate to debug the test I found out, that `select * from test` is working, but `select * from "test"` doesn't.

It was the key finding to actually solve this issue.

In my case it was clear it is some kind of regression, because it worked before I upgraded Spring version.

So I started to search "quotes jdbc spring template" in google. Third in list was this:

https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/20/migrating-to-spring-data-jdbc-2-0